# "SSDT already installed" error when creating SSIS project

Tags: ssis

I do have sql server 2012 express and sql server 2012 enterprise edition installed on a same machine. Express was installed prior to enterprise.

While creating an integration services project, I am getting this error,

> Microsoft visual studio is unable to load this document: to design
>   Integration services packages in sql server data tools.SSDT has to be
>   installed by one of these editions of sql server 2012 standard ,
>   enterprise developer evaluation To install SSDT run SQL Server Setup
>   and Select Sql Serveer data tools

I googled and found articles related to uninstalling and reinstalling all the packages again.

Is there anyway to get rid of this error without uninstalling and re-installing above packages? How can I create projects now?

**Clarification**

While installing MSSql 2012 package, I had installed SSDT by checking the checkbox. In fact I had installed each and component listed there, so there is no need to install them again.

Comment: Did you install the SSDT pieces when you installed 2012 Enterprise?  In previous versions of SQL install you had to explicitly install the BIDS tools, it may be the same in 2012.  You may just need to install the tools piece.  Maybe someone who has recently installed 2012 can chime in with an answer.

Comment: verfied through a quick install that on the feature selection page of the install, there is a check box labelled SSDT that is what you needed.  You should be able to run the install again, and when you get to the feature list, just add that check box to those already installed.  it should just install the missing components.

Comment: @WilliamToddSalzman,Thanks for replying. Please check my clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Converting to an answer.

I verfied through a quick install that on the feature selection page of the install, there is a check box labelled SSDT that is what you needed. You should be able to run the install again, and when you get to the feature list, just add that check box to those already installed. it should just install the missing components.

**Update**

If you had previously installed the tools, your best and cleanest option is to uninstall/reinstall.  Your express version may be causing issues.  Uninstall both versions and reinstall the enterprise or developer version (preferably the developer if you are building a development workstation, or enterprise if this is your production server.)